# putting radio group into JTable

Tags: radio-button, jtable

it seems JTable can only allow checkbox. how can i put a radio group into a cell on the JTable?

Comment: That is very easy: if you need one radio button per row, see the example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/RadioButtonTableExample.htm. If you need to render a group of radio buttons in once cell - that is tricky: you need to return a JPanel as a renderer (as here http://www.mail-archive.com/advanced-swing@eos.dk/msg00249.html), what concerns editor I am not sure :) Try using combobox instead of radio button group.

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite short, so i could have misinterpreted, but anyway
A Boolean is by default registered with the jtable to be rendered/edited by a checkbox.

Depending on the cells'datatype the renderer/editor are retrieved when painting the cells.
you could base a editor/renderer on a JPanel containing two radiobuttons which are grouped using a ButtonGroup.
Depending on what data you want to store in the datamodel, you have various choices.
if for example your datamodel contains ints, then your new editor/renderer should be able to work with that.