# Inserting radio buttons in a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, tablemodel

I have a 2D array of objects which needs to be displayed in a table through a table model class which extends a DefaultTableModel. In addition to the columns needed to accommodate the data included in this array, I would like to add an extra column with radiobuttons, in order to enable the user to make a selection. As table model accepts only arrays of objects or vectors, how should I add radio buttons?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126538/putting-radio-group-into-jtable

Answer (score 1):

By default, `JTable` infers how to render and edit entries based on the entry's class, as discussed in the tutorial article [*Editors and Renderers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), a checkbox allows multiple selections in a column. Substituting a radio button and using a [`ButtonGroup`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) would accommodate a unique selection.